# Direct language support for Russian and Arabic in LUIS and QnA Maker

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Are there any plans to directly support Russian and Arabic in LUIS and QnA Maker in the near future – thus removing the need for the Translation middleware?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about product-roadmaps should be asked of the respective developer and are not a practical programming problem.

Comment: @3-putt did my answer below solve your question?

Comment: It did for QnA Maker but not LUIS

Answer (score 0):

As per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/overview/language-support#query-matching-and-relevance): QnA Maker auto-detects the language of the knowledge base during creation and sets the analyzer accordingly.

Both Arabic and Russian are listed as supported languages in the table below that section as well as having [Language Analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-language-analyzers#language-analyzer-list) available in Azure Search which backs the QnA Maker KB.

The guidelines state that you should have a separate KB per language but if you wanted to have a single KB so with this and the links above you should be able to get something going.

**Edit**

The LUIS languages supported are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support#languages-supported), in terms of future languages I would open an issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/azure-samples/cognitive-services-language-understanding), where you are more likely to get an official response.

Comment: Your answer covers QnA Maker but not LUIS.  Looking at the language support for LUIS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support), I don't see Russian or Arabic.  Can you respond to those missing languages in LUIS?

Comment: Updated my answer.